# Mongoose memory leak when moving subdocument between arrays then modifying it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory-leaks, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is super wacky. I was able to fix it just by moving some code around... but I don't know why—why it broke in the first place or why this fixed it. The purpose of this code is to move a goal object (uses **`Goal`** schema) from the **`goalsInactive`** array to the **`goals`** array of the user. The code below produced a memory error and crashed:

```
for (i = 0; i < user.goalsInactive.length; i++) {
  if (user.goalsInactive[i].code == code) {
    user.goals.splice(ixToInsert, 0, new storage.Goal(user.goalsInactive[i]));
    user.goalsInactive.id(user.goalsInactive[i]._id).remove();
    break;
  }
}
var pastMilestones = user.goals[ixToInsert].pastMilestones;
lastMilestone = pastMilestones && pastMilestones.length && pastMilestones[pastMilestones.length-1];
// crashes with code below active. if lines below disabled, runs fine
if (lastMilestone.type === 'endgoal') {
  lastMilestone.type = "checkpoint"
  pastMilestones.push({
    ymd: cu.getYmdForUser(user),
    name: "Goal Un-Completed",
  });
}
```

I realized that the reason for the crash was a runaway memory issue in `mongoose/lib/document.js`, by logging the paths as they were updating and realizing that it was creating infinite paths. The suspicious original paths looked like this:

```
'goalsInactive.-1.pastMilestones.2.type',
'goalsInactive.-1.pastMilestones',
```

I was able to fix this by changing the code to this:

```
for (i = 0; i < user.goalsInactive.length; i++) {
  if (user.goalsInactive[i].code == code) {
    var pastMilestones = user.goalsInactive[i].pastMilestones;
    lastMilestone = pastMilestones && pastMilestones.length && pastMilestones[pastMilestones.length-1];
    // console.log("lastMilestone", lastMilestone);
    if (lastMilestone.type === 'endgoal') {
      lastMilestone.type = "checkpoint"
      pastMilestones.push({
        ymd: cu.getYmdForUser(user),
        name: "Goal Un-Completed",
      });
    }
    user.goals.splice(ixToInsert, 0, new storage.Goal(user.goalsInactive[i]));
    user.goalsInactive.splice(i,1);
    break;
  }
}
```

(ie modifying the object before moving it). But I don't know why exactly this worked!

I'm using mongoose 4.1.9, so maybe the issue has already been fixed, but I'm wary of updating because updating can produce similar weird issues. It may also be worth noting that the milestone objects also have their own mongoose schema.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,coming back to this almost a year later, it seems that the issue was probably related to me using

```
user.goalsInactive.id(user.goalsInactive[i]._id).remove()
```

rather than

```
user.goalsInactive.pull({_id: user.goalsInactive[i]._id})
```

Calling `remove` is apparently not something you want to do if you're planning to reuse that subdocument in a different array!